# ACPI BIOS Error (bug):

Tags: linux, boot, bios

I am using Zorin OS for 3 months on laptop Asus VivoBook s15.

Yesterday the system asked me for updates and after it finished I had to reboot system. But now always when I'm trying to turn on my device shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr0rN.jpg) error:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failture creating named objecct [\SMIB], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS
(20200717/dsfield-683)
nvme 0000:02:00:0: AMD-VI: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0009 address=0xfedfc00 flags=0x0050]
_
```

I found many similar posts but they always could boot into their device. I can't, I'm stuck on this bug. I tried BIOS update and I have already disabled Secure Boot so what should I do? 
I installed one week ago a [Liquorix Kernel](https://liquorix.net/). Could it be related to that? 
I can't open terminal so I have to write specs from internet:

```
OS: Zorin OS 15.3 Core
Kernel: Liquorix Kernel
PC: ASUS VivoBook S15 M533IA
BIOS version: v303
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4700U
GPU: Integrated - AMD Renoir
```

This is my first post here, so I hope there is everything you need.

**Thanks in advance! Any advice is welcome!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very rough answer:

Your BIOS has tables which are evaluated by Linux during boot. Very often, those tables don't follow the ACPI standard, which nobody notices on Windows because the Vendor who wrote the tables also supply their own Windows driver which work with those tables.

However, there's no driver for Linux, so Linux has to somehow interpret even buggy tables.

The ACPI BIOS you are seeing may or may not be harmful, and may have been already present before the update. It also may be the cause of the hang.

The other error is more serios, the nvme device (SSD) failed during boot, which is probably the reason why the boot stops.

Ways to access the system:

- Try to boot a Linux distribution from an external device (e.g. USB stick), e.g. the [system-rescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/Installing-SystemRescue-on-a-USB-memory-stick/) distro.
- Take out the SSD (if you can), put it in some device (if you have) to read and write it from another PC.

If you get this to work, the first thing I'd do is to re-install your old kernel, and see if the problem persists.

I don't use Zorin OS, so I don't know how they handle things, but it's good practice to always keep the old kernel around when upgrading to a new kernel.

Comment: I installed SystemRescueCD on USB and then started it. It had a resolution only 640x420, so I restarted the PC. After restarting, Zorin OS released me into 'ZorinOS repair mode' and I had the opportunity to boot the system according to the upgrade stages. So I chose the stage before yesterday's installation and Zorin OS started normally. Now I can back up my data finally. I know I didn't follow your steps, but the problem was at least partially resolved. So **thank you so much**, without you I would be at the end.

Comment: Don't forget to check `dmesg` in the working stage to see if the ACPI error is present there at well. Also write down the kernel versions in the working stage (and the new stage, if you can).

Comment: I chacked the `dmesg` and it shows: ```ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\SMIB], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20200717/dsfield-639)
fbcon: Taking over console
Warning: NsLookup: Type mismatch on SMIB (Integer), searching for (RegionField) (20200717/nsaccess-703) ``` Kernel: `Linux 5.9.0-11.2-liquorix-amd64`

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIf6y.jpg) is what it shows. Working kernel is `Linux 5.9.0-11.2-liquorix-amd64` and not working is `Linux 5.9.0-11.3-liquorix-amd64`. Should I try the 'recovery mode'?

Comment: Ok, so the ACPI BIOS error is not the reason. The nvme error may or may not be related to the actual upgrade, maybe it was just a bad block in an unfortunate position (or whatever it was). Try upgrading again, so you overwrite the potential bad block. As I wrote, I am not familiar with Zorin OS, so I can't tell you *how* to do that in detail, and I don't know what the recovery mode actually does.

Comment: I did as you said. The kernel is updated to: `5.9.0-12.1-liquorix-amd64` and now everything works. Again **Thank you very much!**, you really helped me!